# Access chaincode/smartcontract methods on hyperledger fabrix 2.4 as REST endpoints

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

## Access chaincode/smartcontract methods on hyperledger fabrix 2.4 as REST endpoints

Hello all, is it possible to expose the chaincode/smart contract methods, which was deployed on a channel in hyperledger fabric test-network as REST endpoints to use on a frontend which I am working on?

If yes, how can one do it, are there any references which I can use?

I am running the test-network on wsl2 on a windows machine

I have been able to deploy and instantiate the chaincode on the channel and run the invoke and query methods through the CLI.
I want to expose them as REST API so that I could use them in my front-end web application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you probably need to take is to write an application that both:

1. Exposes an appropriate REST API to REST clients; and
2. Interacts with Fabric using the [Fabric client APIs](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/) when REST requests are received.

There is an [example of this approach](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide/applications/rest-api) within the [full-stack-asset-transfer-guide](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide) Fabric sample. Depending on your requirements, you might want to implement more thorough error handling than is demonstrated by that sample. There is a simple example of error handling behaviour in the [application development documentation](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide/docs/ApplicationDev/03-ApplicationOverview.md#retry-of-transaction-submit) of the same sample.

One more important consideration is the cryptographic identity that you will use to interact with Fabric. Your options are either:

1. Have one (or more) identity for the client application, and all REST requests drive Fabric invocations using this application identity.
2. Have Fabric interactions use identities owned by each REST client.

If using a single, application identity, it will be important to have some means of authenticating your REST clients. You might want to consider audit of who is doing what.

If the REST clients have their own cryptographic identity, they will want to keep their private keys private and not share them with your REST application. This means that messages sent to Fabric must be signed (using the private key) by the REST client, not your REST application. A pattern for achieving this is "off-line signing", where the REST application builds the Fabric request, returns the message (or just its digest/hash) to the REST client to sign, then attaches this client-generated signature to the message sent to Fabric. There is a brief overview of this approach with code examples in the [API documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/main/api/node/interfaces/Contract.html).